# How to find the derivative of $\operatorname{arcsinh}(3x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know 
The derivative of $\operatorname{arcsinh}(x) = 1/(x^2+1)^{1/2}$
But if I derivative $\operatorname{arcsinh}(3x)$ 
Why it doesn't equal to 
$(\operatorname{arcsinh}(3x))^{-1} (1/(9x^2+1)) (3)$ ??

Thanks all

Comment: Substitute $u=3x$ and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the chain rule, we get that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\operatorname{arcsinh}(3x)\right) = \dfrac{\frac{d}{dx}(3x)}{\sqrt{(3x)^2 + 1}} = \dfrac 3{\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}}$$

Comment: Could use another UV +1

Answer (score 1):

Where did the factor $(\operatorname{arcsinh} (3x))^{-1}$ come from?  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20arcsinh%283x%29) agrees with $\frac 3{\sqrt{9x^2+1}}$